# How to add and retrieve user attributes in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I've been trying to implement attribute based access control in my blockchain. The approach I followed is as follows:

I've added attributes in `membersrvc.yaml` file and also passed attributes in my transaction request payload. Passed the attributes even while registering the user. However when I try to retrieve the attributes in my chaincode, using `fooval, err := stub.ReadCertAttribute("foo")` , I get an error saying,

```
Error:Transaction or query returned with failure: Couldn\'t get attribute \'foo\'. Error: Failed retrieving extension.'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you retrieve the payload for the specific block created and base64 decode it. You'll see exactly what the chaincode sees of your input attributes

Comment: Did you solved that? Got the same error and the same config

Comment: Can you show the transaction request ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you did everything except enabling attributes feature in general in membersrvc.yaml.
It should be enabled in membersrvc.yaml here:
aca:
   enabled: true

Comment: No, I did that. Everything seems right but still something's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "secureContext" and "attributes" parameters in your deploy/invoke/query request